# Windows 7: Where is the log of shutdowns?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

**The underlying problem:** I have a user on a Windows 7 machine who claims that they always close all open windows (FireFox, Thunderbird, MS Office, ...) and then shut down the PC - yet sometimes when they boot the machine, the user claims that the machine would come up and show all application windows open as if nobody had closed them. The claim goes on, that this sometimes occurs even without requiring a login/password.

**My research:** Due to the random nature of the phenomenon, I was not able to reproduce the behaviour. No matter how I quit the Windows session (Shut down, Sleep, Hibernate), Windows would always require a password.

Furthermore, it seems that upon login after a shutdown, Windows 7 will always present a clean desktop, as there simply is no feature that would relaunch or continue user applications which were still running when the user logged off last.

**My conjecture:** The phenomenon is caused due to the user forgetting to close their applications and then accidentally hitting *Sleep* or *Hibernate* instead of shutting down.

**My question:** How can I check whether the last shutdowns of the system were clean or not (i.e. what is the Windows 7 equivalent of Ubuntu's `last -x`)?

Any other pointers or explanations to the phenomenon welcome.

Answer (score 4):

#### Where is the log of shutdowns?

You need to look in the system event log, using [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7).

The following events are relevant.

**Sleep/Hibernate:**

```
Log Name: System
Event ID: 41
Source: Kernel-Power
Type: Critical
Description:
The last sleep transition was unsuccessful. 

Log Name: System
Event ID: 42
Source: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Type: Information
Description:
The system is entering sleep.
```

**Shutdown:**

```
Log Name: System
Event ID: 6006
Source: EventLog
Type: Information
Description:
The Event log service was stopped.

Log Name: System
Event ID: 6008
Source: Event Log
Type: Error
Description:
The previous system shutdown at Time on Date was unexpected.
```